# rxjs: why the stream emit twice when another stream use take(1)

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

When I use `take(1)`, it will console.log twice `1`, like below code:

```
  const a$ = new BehaviorSubject(1).pipe(publishReplay(1), refCount());
  a$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe();
  a$.subscribe((v) => console.log(v)); // emit twice (1 1)
```

But when I remove `take(1)` or remove `publishReplay(1), refCount()`, it follow my expected (only one `1` console.log).

```
  const a$ = new BehaviorSubject(1).pipe(publishReplay(1), refCount());
  a$.subscribe();
  a$.subscribe((v) => console.log(v)); // emit 1

  // or

  const a$ = new BehaviorSubject(1);
  a$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe();
  a$.subscribe((v) => console.log(v)); // emit 1
```

Why?

Version: rxjs 6.5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first have a look at how `publishReplay` is [defined](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/publishReplay.ts#L24):

```js
const subject = new ReplaySubject<T>(bufferSize, windowTime, scheduler);

return (source: Observable<T>) => multicast(() => subject, selector!)(source) as ConnectableObservable<R>;
```

`multicast()` will return a `ConnectableObservable`, which is an observable that exposes the `connect` method. Used in conjunction with `refCount`, the source will be subscribed when the first subscriber registers and will automatically unsubscribe from the source when there are no more active subscribers. The **multicasting** behavior is achieved by placing a `Subject`(or any kind of subject) between the data consumers and the data producer.

`() => subject` implies that the **same subject instance** will be used every time the source will be subscribed, which is an important aspect as to why you're getting that behavior.

```js
const src$ = (new BehaviorSubject(1)).pipe(
  publishReplay(1), refCount() // 1 1
);

src$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe()

src$.subscribe(console.log)
```

Let's see what would be the flow of the above snippet:

```js
src$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe()
```

Since it's the first subscriber, the source(the `BehaviorSubject`) will be subscribed. When this happens, it will emit `1`, which will have to *go through* the `ReplaySubject` in use. Then, the subject will pass along that value to its subscribers(e.g `take(1)`). But because you're using `publishReplay(1)`(1 indicates the `bufferSize`), that value will be cached by that subject.

```js
src$.subscribe(console.log)
```

The way [`refCount` works](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/refCount.ts#L73-L79) is that it first subscribes to the `Subject` in use, and then to the source:

```js
const refCounter = new RefCountSubscriber(subscriber, connectable);

// Subscribe to the subject in use
const subscription = connectable.subscribe(refCounter); 

if (!refCounter.closed) {
  // Subscribe to the source
  (<any> refCounter).connection = connectable.connect();
}
```

Incidentally, [here's what happens on `connectable.subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/ConnectableObservable.ts#L26-L28):

```js
_subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>) {
  return this.getSubject().subscribe(subscriber);
}
```

Since the subject is a `ReplaySubject`, it will send the cached values to its newly registered subscriber(hence the **first** `1`). Then, because there were no subscribers before(due to `take(1)`, which completes after the first emission), the source will be unsubscribed again, which should explain why you're getting the **second** `1`.

---

If you'd like to get only one `1` value, you can achieve this by making sure that every time the source is subscribed, a different subject will be used:

```js
const src$ = (new BehaviorSubject(1)).pipe(
  shareReplay({ bufferSize:1, refCount: true }) // 1
);

src$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe()

src$.subscribe(console.log)
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-publishreplay-vs-sharereplay?file=index.ts).